# No access to symlink folder on NTFS partition

Tags: symlink, ext4, automounting, ntfs, fstab

I am using an NTFS parition for storing data I like to access both from Ubuntu and Windows 7. On my Ubuntu *HOME* partition, I like to link the folder `Assets` in order to access it from an application running on Ubuntu. Therefore, I created the following link.

```
ln -s /media/data/Assets/ ~/bin/SomeJavaApp/data/assets
```

When I try to access the data within the application, the following error message appears.

```
Error message: Could not acquire data access
```

The NTFS parition is attached via auto mount in `/etc/fstab`. Here is the relevant configuration setting:

```
# Data partition auto mount.
UUID=159EBA47019D5D33 /media/data ntfs defaults,umask=007,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

My *HOME* partition is formatted with ext4. The application I use is written in Java. Is there something, I can do about this besides copying the files to the *HOME* partition?

---

I also get a Java error message when I start the application from the console.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Could not acquire data access
```

**@Gilles**:
The output of `ls -ld /media/data /media/data/Assets ~/bin/SomeJavaApp/data/assets` is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jjd jjd    92 Aug  9 11:01 /home/jjd/bin/SomeJavaApp/data/assets -> /media/data/Assets/
drwxrwx--- 1 jjd jjd 28672 Aug  6 14:49 /media/data
drwxrwx--- 1 jjd jjd  4096 Aug  8 14:32 /media/data/Assets/
```

The path I choose in the application is: `/home/jjd/bin/SomeJavaApp/data/assets`.

Comment: Is your partition mounted rw? and what are the file permissions on the folder assets?. Also, you might have a problem with case-sensitivity here. The error has a capital 'A' while your file path has a small 'a'

Comment: According to [this website](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html) the `defaults` setting in my `fstab` means that I mount the partition as `read-write`. Regarding the case-sensitivity: I only access the files within the folder and therefore do not expect a problem there. How about the `umask`, should it be `000`?

Comment: What path do you provide to the application? Please copy-paste. What is the output of `ls -ld /media/data /media/data/Assets ~/bin/myapp/data/assets`?

Comment: The name or the resource that appears at the end of the error messages `Could not acquire data access ...` is merely the alias I enter in the application. Therefore, it is irrelevant to the problem. I removed the string.